# How to use swig template in geddy js

Tags: swig, geddy

I have this error when start geddy

TypeError: Object # has no method 'init'
at new swig (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\adapters\swig.js:25:15)
at C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\adapters\index.js:42:14
at setOptions (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\adapters\index.js:44:5)
at Adapter.set (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\adapters\index.js:97:21)
at Partial.renderSelf (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\partial.js:125:13)
at handleData (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\partial.js:99:16)
at C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\partial.js:117:9
at fs.js:266:14
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a breaking change in the last Swig update, and has been fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/mde/geddy/pull/460).

I'll check now with @mde to see if we've pushed it out to NPM yet.

Comment: Fix pushed to NPM, Geddy v0.10.2.